# In AWS , How can I attached volumes list for particular VM using REST APIs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

How can I get the attached Volumes list for a particular instance\VM using the REST API?

IE: What is the REST API equivalent for this AWS CLI command:

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes --region us-west --filters Name=attachment.instance-id,values=i-eeh33heue3
```

Answer (score 5):

The API command is typically the CLI command without punctuation. [It's documented here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeVolumes.html).

Sample request (you can add parameters for instance ID)

```
https://ec2.amazonaws.com/?Action=DescribeVolumes&AUTHPARAMS
```

Comment: Thank you. so below request is working request_parameters = 'Action=DescribeVolumes&Version=2013-10-15' but when I try this with filter it is not working . request_parameters = 'Action=DescribeVolumes&Version=2013-10-15&Filter.1.Name=attachment.instance-id&Filter.1.value=i-019c4383c4e0d670e'

Comment: I don't know the answer to that sorry. Your question has been answered, if you have another question around filtering please ask a new question, someone else will be able to help.